# Convert date to month/year format for time series

Tags: r, date, time-series

I have some have some water quality sample data.

```
> dput(GrowingArealog90s[1:10,])
structure(list(SampleDate = structure(c(6948, 6949, 6950, 7516, 
7517, 7782, 7783, 7784, 8092, 8106), class = "Date"), Flog90 =  c(1.51851393987789, 
1.48970743802793, 1.81243963000062, 0.273575501327576, 0.874218895695207, 
1.89762709129044, 1.44012088794774, 0.301029995663981, 1.23603370361931, 
0.301029995663981)), .Names = c("SampleDate", "Flog90"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

This data is collected monthly, although some months are missed over the 25 year period.

I know there is so much help out there for converting dates to different formats but I have not been able to figure this out.  I want to create a time series with just a month/year format, so that I can do things like decompose the data by month and run seasonal kendalls and such.  I have tried so many different ways of converting my date to the desired format that I have completely confused myself.  I don't care about the exact format as long as it is recognized month/year.

I also need to fill in the missing months with NAs.

I tried uploading the "SampleDate" column in a numeric format, "yyyymm". I could then merge that data frame with another that contained all the dates I need.

```
GA90 <- merge(Dates, GrowingArealog90s, by.x = "Date", by.y = "Date", all.x = TRUE)
```

However, when I converted the resulting data frame to a time series it would not recognize the 12 month frequency.

```
 GA90ts <- as.ts(GA90, frequency(12))

> GA90ts
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 324 
Frequency = 1
```

Any help with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it with `zoo`. You'll get a warning, but it's OK for now. You'll get a series with mon/yy.

```
series <-structure(list(SampleDate = structure(c(6948, 6949, 6950, 7516,
7517, 7782, 7783, 7784, 8092, 8106), class = "Date"), Flog90 =  c(1.51851393987789,
1.48970743802793, 1.81243963000062, 0.273575501327576, 0.874218895695207,
1.89762709129044, 1.44012088794774, 0.301029995663981, 1.23603370361931,
0.301029995663981)), .Names = c("SampleDate", "Flog90"), class = c("tbl_df",
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

library(zoo)
series <-as.data.frame(series) #to drop dplyr class
series.zoo <-zoo(series[,-1,drop=FALSE],as.yearmon(series[,1]))
```

Best practice would be to keep your series with actual date and use `as.yearmon` or `as.yearmon` only when you actually need to make calculations or `aggregate.zoo` by month and year.

The following is a matter of taste,  but I've dealt with a lot of time series and I think `zoo` is superior to `ts` and `xts`. Much more flexible.

Now, to fill in missing values, you have to create a vector of dates. Here, I'm using a `zoo` object with actual dates. I then use `na.locf`, which is "last observation carry forward". You could also look at `na.approx`.

```
series.zoo <-zoo(series[,-1,drop=FALSE],(series[,1]))
my.seq <-seq.Date(first(series[,1,drop=FALSE]), last(series[,1,drop=FALSE]),by="month")
merged <-merge.zoo(series.zoo,zoo(,my.seq))
na.locf(merged)
```

**UPDATE**

With aggregate.

```
GrowingArealog90s <-structure(list(SampleDate = structure(c(6948, 6949, 6950, 7516,
7517, 7782, 7783, 7784, 8092, 8106), class = "Date"), Flog90 =  c(1.51851393987789,
1.48970743802793, 1.81243963000062, 0.273575501327576, 0.874218895695207,
1.89762709129044, 1.44012088794774, 0.301029995663981, 1.23603370361931,
0.301029995663981)), .Names = c("SampleDate", "Flog90"), class = c("tbl_df",
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

library(zoo);library(xts)
GrowingArealog90s <-as.data.frame(GrowingArealog90s) #to remove dplyr format
GrowingArealog90s.zoo <-zoo(GrowingArealog90s[,-1,drop=FALSE],as.Date(GrowingArealog90s[,1]))

#First aggregate by month. I chose to get the mean per month
GrowingArealog90s.agg <-aggregate(GrowingArealog90s.zoo, as.yearmon, mean) #replace mean with last to get last reading of the month

#Then create a sequence of months and merge it
my.seq <-seq.Date(first(GrowingArealog90s[,1]), last(GrowingArealog90s[,1]),by="month")
merged <-merge.zoo(GrowingArealog90s.agg ,zoo(,as.yearmon(my.seq)))
na.locf(merged)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  when I run the "my.seq" line it gives me the following error: "Error in seq.Date(first(GrowingArealog90s[, 1, drop = FALSE]), last(GrowingArealog90s[,  : 
  'from' must be of length 1".

Comment: Try this: `my.seq <-seq.Date(first(GrowingArealog90s[,1]), last(GrowingArealog90s[,1]),by="month")`

Comment: Also, make sure GrowingArealog90s is not a `tbl_df` from `dplyr`. It has to be a data.frame. `dplyr` is for tables, not time series.

Comment: Thanks again, that got me closer to what I'm looking for, however it added NAs where I didn't want them.  I want one line per month and it added in NAs where there were already values for some months, like April of 1989 below.  > head(merged)
              Flog90
1989-01-05 1.3774064
1989-02-05        NA
1989-03-05        NA
1989-03-09 0.8682064
1989-04-05        NA
1989-04-06 0.9364644

Comment: Of course!  I'm back on Monday.  Take your time, much appreciated!

Comment: Perfect!  P. Lapointe I can not thank you enough.  You have helped me tremendously!